# How to use cropped image using croppie js to php and use it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, crop

I am trying to create image overlay app, which will add water mark to an uploaded image. I have done my image overlay app using this [tutorial](http://serve.shanechism.com/projects/FacebookPicOverlay/uploader.php), 
now I need to add a cropping feature using [croppie.js](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/). I want to pass the output of the croppie js to this php.

```
<?php

# Check to see if the form has been submitted or not:
if( !isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

    # Form has not been submitted, show our uploader form and stop the script
    require_once( "uploader.html" );
    exit();

}else{

    # Form has been submitted, begin processing data

    # Include the function file then call it with the uploaded picture:
    # TIP: The "../../ portion is a relative path. You will need to change this
    #      path to fit your website's directory structure.
    require_once( 'FacebookPicOverlay.php' );

    # Create the FacebookTagger object using our upload value given to us by uploader.html
    $fbt = new FacebookPicOverlay();

    # Let's say we're using this script to do an image overlay. Let's invoke the
    # overlay method, which will then return the image file relative to the resources
    # folder (ex: will return resources/processed/imagename.jpg).
    try {
        $image = $fbt->overlay( $_FILES['picture_upload'] );
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        print( "<b>Oops!</b> " . $e->getMessage() );
        print( "<br /><br /><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Please go back and try again</a>" );
        exit();
    }

    # This will delete all images created more than two days ago (by default).
    # This is helpful in keeping our processed folder at a reasonable file size.
    $fbt->maintenance();

    require_once( "success.html" );

}   

# That's all, folks!
?>
```

Please help me out with uploader form. Thanks

Comment: There is no form and barely any code. After cropping, can you get the data out as a blob (like, with `canvas.getImageData`) and then pass to php to process it? Thats all you need to do, but the code provided really tells us nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using croppie too and I get the data from the Base64 code information displayed in the image preview.

Example:

JQuery:

```
var uploadCrop;
function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            uploadCrop.croppie("bind", { url: e.target.result });
            $("#upload-preview").addClass("ready");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

var w = $(window).width(), h = $(window).height();

console.log('window width: ' + w);
console.log('window height: ' + h);
if (w < 400) var wCalc = 25;
else if (w < 350) var wCalc = 50;
else if (w < 300) var wCalc = 75;
else var wCalc = 0;

var uploadCrop = $("#upload-preview").croppie({
    setZoom: 1.0,
    enableOrientation: true,
    quality: 1,
    viewport: {
        width: 250-wCalc,
        height: 250-wCalc,
        type: "circle"
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 320-wCalc,
        height: 320-wCalc
    },
    exif: true
});
$("#upload").on("change", function () {
    readFile(this);
});
function output(node) {
var existing = $("#result .croppie-result");
    if (existing.length > 0) {
    existing[0].parentNode.replaceChild(node, existing[0]);
    } else {
    $("#result")[0].appendChild(node);
    }
}
function popupResult(result) {
    var html;
    if (result.html) {
        html = result.html;
    }
    if (result.src) {
        $("#result").html("<img id=\"canvas\" src=\"" + result.src + "\" />");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="btn btn-grey btn-file">
    <input id="upload" name="file_data" type="file" accept="image/*" /> Browse
</span>

</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="upload-preview" class="mt30 mb35"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is the part where you handle the click event and store the image information in `resp`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ajax-post', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    thisVar = $(this);
    var img_width = $('.cr-image').attr('width');

    if (img_width) {
        // Image Base64
        uploadCrop.croppie("result", {type: "canvas", size: {width: 600, height: 600}}).then(function (resp) {
            popupResult({src: resp});
            saveAjax(thisVar, resp);
        });
    } else {
        saveAjax(thisVar);
    }
});
```

`saveAjax` is my own function to handle ajax requests. You just have to pass `resp` which contains the image information or write that ajax request in the function itself.

More about this method and topic: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: thanks for ur help! But how to pass this to my uploader.php that i mentioned above. I am totally new to php development thats y!!  Thanks a lot for your help